# .htaccess redirect from subdirectory to another domain with proxy

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following 2 directories.com

http://www.site1.com/dir
http://www.site2.com/dir

I want all traffic to http://www.site1.com/dir to redirect to http://www.site2.com while keeping http://www.site1.com/dir in the address bar. I have mod_proxy enabled, but I can't figure out the proper lines to put into the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On `www.site1.com` enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(dir1/.*)$ http://www.site2.com/$1 [L,NC,P]
```

`P` flag here will make use of `mod_proxy` and make `www.site1.com` act as proxy server to forward request from `www.site2.com`. URL will not change in browser.

Comment: Thanks! However, this seems to recognize only one subdirectory in. Is there anyway to have it be able to forward multiple subdirectories - ex: site1.com/dir1/dir2/dir3 > site2.com/dir1/dir2/dir3

Comment: Yes sure see edit. Now every path on `www.site1.com` will be proxied to `www.site2.com`

Comment: This forwards the entire domain. I just want it to forward everything in dir1 + every child of dir1